# ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu from source Checkout Error

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, git, rosinstall, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there a new or updated rosinstall file for installing Fuerte from source?

From the wiki: ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

It pulls down the rosinstall from: ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-full.rosinstall

In this file it pulls down the repos from: github.com/wg-debs

The files in that repo no longer exist as they have been moved to this repo I believe: github.com/ros-gbp

Now that the files have been moved, I am not sure about the correct versions I am suppose to pull down as they are not the same.

Does anyone have an updated rosinstall to install the Full version of ROS source for Fuerte?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51317/ros-fuerte-on-ubuntu-from-source-checkout-error/) by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file has been fixed as of 01/10/2013.  Here is the new rosinstall: http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-full.rosinstall

---

Originally posted by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) with karma: 377 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use a rosinstall file at
http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no

You can change the arguments in the URL to get what you need. The instructions in the wiki probably need to be updated.

EDIT: The above only works for overlays of core packages, the url is not suitable for source-installs.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on 2013-01-03**:
Someone should update the wiki.  I have a feeling many other people are going to run into the same problems.  They probably should just update the file at ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-full.rosinstall

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-09**:
You are right: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/332

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I modified the file by hand for ros-base and used with `rosinstall --catkin ~/ros-underlay file:///home/rosuser/fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall`

I can't post file because my karma is insufficient :(
[www.madefree.eu/downloads/ros/fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall](http://www.madefree.eu/downloads/ros/fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall)

---

Originally posted by [enodiesop](https://answers.ros.org/users/3856/enodiesop/) with karma: 41 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1